# Custom directory to include JS and CSS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I have got a theme from themeforest which has a `plugins/` directory with 20-30 directories inside that with `js/` and `css/` folders.

So I need to have a folder outside of the default sails `js/` and `styles/` called `plugins/`, which will then be included in the grunt build.

I tried to copy the usual `jsFilesToInject` and replicate it all with this:

```
var plugInJSFilesToInject = [
   // All of the rest of your client-side js files
   // will be injected here in no particular order.
   'plugins/**/*.js'
];
```

Then specifing it in the `sails-linker:devJs` like so:

```
devJs: {
        options: {
                startTag: '<!--SCRIPTS-->',
                endTag: '<!--SCRIPTS END-->',
                fileTmpl: '<script src="%s"></script>',
                appRoot: '.tmp/public'
        },
        files: {
                '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
                'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
                'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').jsFilesToInject,
                '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').plugInJSFilesToInject,
                'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').plugInJSFilesToInject,
                'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').plugInJSFilesToInject
        }
},
```

And recieved this error when running `sails lift`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "sails-linker:devJs" (sails-linker) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

This also needs to be done for a `css/` directory, which is why I definitely need to have it outside of the `js/` or `styles` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just placing the `plugins/` in the same `jsFilesToInject` array, because there is no reason why it can't go in there:

```
var plugInJSFilesToInject = [
  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/**/*.js',
   // Plugins go here
  'plugins/**/*.js'
];
```